# Generating thousands of records in salesforce using Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, execute-anonymous

can I run an apex class through execute anonymous to generate thousands of records of an object in salesforce?

```
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
for(integer i=0;i<200000;i++){
Account acc = new Account(Name='test'+i);
accList.add(acc);    
}
Insert accList;
```

If I run this code what are the implications? Any governor limit hit here?

Comment: You will hit the System.LimitException:  :Too many DML rows: 10001 when you try to execute above code. You can not able to insert more than 10000 records in above call.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Pls see the edit in the question. Changed 200,000 to 200000.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. :(

Comment: I will resist the urge to lmgtfy but seriously... this is a really easy [search](https://www.google.com/webhp?=governor%20limits%20apex#q=governor+limits+apex) to perform yourself.

Comment: Agreed! Aplogies for wasting the time. I wasn't able to connect the dots for some reason. I am clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only affect 10,000 rows of data at once (see [Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)). If you need more than this, you'll need to use Batch Apex.

> Total number of records processed as a result of DML statements, Approval.process, or database.emptyRecycleBin
>
> 10,000

Comment: You are so quick :)